# Page redirect following js alert - alternatives to include and header

Tags: javascript, php

Within the script that processes a html form after the user submits it, I am using the js alert to notify the user of problems. If i follow the alert with PHP 'include' for the page the form is on, the alert is sent to the top of the page and it changes my formatting (through the character encoding i think).

```
if(!$last_name){
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Your last name is required.")';
    echo '</script>';
    include 'join.php';
    exit(); 
}
```

If i use PHP header() it takes the user to the page all over again and they loose what they have entered in the form and have to start all over.

```
if(!$last_name){
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Your last name is required.")';
    echo '</script>';
    header('Location: join.php');
    exit(); 
}
```

After the form is submitted and if the user receives the js alert (and clicks ok) , i would like the user to remain on the page with the fields filled in as they were when the submitted the form. Any suggestions? to solve this in PHP?

I know I could just redirect them to a page with the specific error on it, but I am trying to avoid jhaving to make all those pages.

Comment: You cant echo and then redirect

Comment: @JelleKeizer You can't echo then header(location: '') ???

Comment: No, if you echo php auto sends the headers. It doesnt make any sense. http://www.sitepoint.com/form-validation-with-php/ try a simpel tutorial like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use AJAX and wait for a response, when you receive the response you could process it through javascript getting javascript to then handle the errors.

You need to be a bit more clear on what you are trying to do.

---

Are you trying to get a user to fill out a form, when the form isnt filled out correctly, it instead tells the user to fill out the missing fields, and not redirect to the new page?

If that is the case, you can write a function in javascript, and bind the submit button to that, if the check fails, dont submit, otherwise if all is fine, proceed.

Comment: Thanks @NZ Mikey, I changed the question to hopefully clarify

Comment: I would still suggest using AJAX, upon submitting, it can get the error, and it wont redirect, it will leave the person on the page without reloading at all, is this not what you want?

Comment: that's what I want, I was checking to see if there were any alternatives.

Comment: I dont think there is a way to do it directly in php as php is server side, you need browser side to do what you are wanting done.  AJAX or just Javascript would be the ways to go.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve 
1. Javascript Validation ?
2. Server side Validation?

For Javascript Validation - use onsubmit event of form and validate inputs before submitting the form. if input not as per validations don't submit the form and just alert and put focus of field which is not as per requirement.

For Server side validation - submit form, validate input, take all errors into php variable and echo it on top or adjacent to input fields where you want it to be.. if all input fine then use header to redirect user to other page.

Please clarify proper details..

Comment: Thanks @vineet verma, I changed the question to hopefully clarify